# Obstacle detection

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I use createjs for development.
My game has a character and element in the middle.
The element in the middle is an obstacle.
How to determine that there is an obstacle in front of the player?
The fact is that if you click on the place that is behind the object, the character will fly this object.

Comment: Hi @ANTU and welcome to SO. Your question is quite broad, because I believe it potentially involve collision detection and pathfinding. You could check this article on MDN about collision detection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection or this one about QuadTree: http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/03/javascript-quadtree-implementation/
Anyway I advise you to ask on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ which is more about game development obviously. Good luck

Comment: Also, have a look at this website, it is an extremely useful resource when learning game development, specifically pathfinding: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/